# What return type should I declare a function with if I don't care about the return value?

Tags: c, return-value, return-type, function-declaration

In my C file, I am calling a function that is defined in a generated file, `lex.yy.c`:

```
yy_scan_string(input);
```

which is declared as following in `lex.yy.c`:

```
YY_BUFFER_STATE yy_scan_string(yyconst char *yystr);
```

And in turn `YY_BUFFER_STATE` is an `typedef`:

```
typedef struct yy_buffer_state *YY_BUFFER_STATE;
```

None of these are available to include from a header file. While in order to call `yy_scan_string` I will have to declare it first.

What would be the best way to declare this function in my source file, when I don't care about the return value at all, and it's infeasible to include the type definition of the return type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The universally accepted procedure is to define the function in a header-file and include that file at the start of the file you call it from.

If for some reason that header file hasn't be provided you would make it.

If it's only a handful of functions you could declare them locally in the .c file.

The function returns a pointer to the structure so you can use the forward declaration:

```
typedef struct yy_buffer_state *YY_BUFFER_STATE;
```

However I can only recommend very strongly you remove those declarations to their own file.

Answer (score 4):

Declare it as exactly how you have described but with the struct defined as an opaque type. As long as you don't dereference the return value (and it sounds like you won't) then that'll work just fine.

```
struct yy_buffer_state;
typedef struct yy_buffer_state *YY_BUFFER_STATE;
YY_BUFFER_STATE yy_scan_string(yyconst char *yystr);
```

Comment: Is the opaque struct declaration required here? gcc does not give any warning/error if I omit the first line.

Comment: @RyanLi The second-line implicitly forward declares 'struct yy_buffer_state' so as you point out the first line is not required.

Answer (score -4):

Just make its type `void`

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void helloworld();

void main()
{
  helloworld();
}

void helloworld()
{
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: uff....not again...leave the `main()`..take any other function for your example...